# How to calculate the average correlation among stocks

Tags: excel, vba, correlation, lower-bound

So I´m wondering how I can calculate the average correlation among stocks whose correlations are between 20% (LB) and 70% (UB).

I'm supposed to use this VBA function `AvgRhoBounded(Ret, LB, UB)`

LB stands for Lower bound and UB stands for upper bound. 
Ret is the return data I already have. So far this is what I've done and I'm not sure if it right..

THE CODE:

```
Function AvgRhoBounded(RET, LB, UB)

    ' get number of assets

    n = data.Columns.Count

    ' add up all returns

    total_rho = 0
    n_rho = 0
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = i + 1 To n

            rho_ij = Application.WorksheetFunction.Correl(data.Columns(i), data.Columns(j))
            total_rho = total_rho + rho_ij
            n_rho = n_rho + 1

        Next j
    Next i

    ' return average correlations

    AvgRho = total_rho / n_rho


'calculating the average correlation between stocks whose correlation are between 20% and 70%

Dim LB As String
Dim Lowerbound As String

Dim RET As String

Dim UB As String
Dim Upperbound As String

If LB = 20 Then
Lowerbound = 20

ElseIf UB = 70 Then
Upperbound = 70

End If

End Function
```

Comment: okay thanks, i will do that now

Comment: I do not see `RET` used anywhere in your function, so it will never have data in it. Also, you may want to explain how you defined `data` and how it is populated with data.